# Pandas getting a list of all non Nan values

Tags: python, pandas, list

I want to get all non nan values in a dataframe like:

```
    foo   foo2   foo3  foo4
a   NY    WA     AZ    NaN
b   DC    NaN    NaN   NaN
c   MA    CA     NaN   NaN
```

output:

```
[NY, WA, AZ, DC, MA, CA]
```

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find an exact answer for this question, so when I combined several answers into one, 

thought to share the answer:

```
df.stack().values
```

The trick is that stack() is removing nans while stacking the values, 
the rest is just standard way of getting dataframe values into list.